# How can I reset a head that used to have shape keys?

Tags: shape-keys

If I take a shape, in this case a head, with Zero shape keys, duplicate it, then Join as Shapes, moving the new slider changes the shape of the original head.

Usually doing this does nothing to distort the original shape, so what is still in the shape that I need to delete and how do I delete it?

It seems like the shape doesn't want to Basis?

Comment: Thinking about it, I suppose I could export the head as an OBJ then re-import it back to the scene.

Comment: I found a bone that wasn't reset causing a distortion. My bad.